# Как через js установить css-свойства с префиксами?

Tags: javascript, css, css3

Мне через JS нужно задать css-свойства и свойство transition в том числе. Хочу добавить через JS вендорные префиксы. С использованием cssText скрипт не работает, а без них добавляется просто transition без префиксов. Как мне через JS добавить transition с префиксами?

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    
    class MenuToggler{
        constructor(data){
            this.menuTriggerSelector = data.menuTriggerSelector;
            this.menuSelector = data.menuSelector;
            this.type = data.type || 'appear'; //type of Apperance
            
            this.menuTrigger = document.querySelector(`${this.menuTriggerSelector}`);
            this.menu = document.querySelector(`${this.menuSelector}`);
            
            this.transitionTime = data.transitionTime || '.25s';            
            this.init();
        }
        
        init(){
            if (this.type == 'appear'){
                // add first styles, makes elem invisible and untouchuble
                
                this.menu.style.height = '0px';
                this.menu.style.opacity = '0';
                this.menu.style.transition = `opacity ${this.transitionTime} linear ${this.transitionTime}, height 0s linear 0s`;
                this.menu.style.cssText = `-webkit-transition: opacity ${this.transitionTime} linear ${this.transitionTime}, height 0s linear 0s`;
                this.menu.style.cssText = `-o-transition: opacity ${this.transitionTime} linear ${this.transitionTime}, height 0s linear 0s`;
            }
        }
    }
    
    const menuToggler1 = new MenuToggler({
        menuTriggerSelector: '.burger',
        menuSelector: '.links-wrapper'
    });
    
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С помощью **kebab-case** -> **camelCase**

`-webkit-transition` превращается в `webkitTransition`

```js
// Можно посмотреть как это выглядит на примере всех стилей,
// которые начинаются с align...
const div = document.createElement('div')
document.body.appendChild(div)

Object.entries(getComputedStyle(div))
  .filter(([p, v]) => (p.startsWith('align') || v.startsWith('align')))
  .forEach(([p, v]) => console.log(`${p} -> ${v}`))
```

**UPDATE:** Вышеуказанные свойства не могут существовать во всех браузерах сразу

- -webkit- (Chrome, Safari, iOS Safari / iOS WebView, Android)
- -moz- (Fire Fox)
- -ms- (Edge, Internet Explorer)
- -o- (Opera, Opera Mini)

... и, соответственно, установить их и просмотреть в консоли нет возможности.

Если есть желание устанавливать префикс через JS, необходимо проверять наличие искомого свойства. Делать это в каждой строчке кода неразумно.

Пишем небольшую библиотеку. Наша задача делегировать корректную установку префиксов для любого браузера, без использования этих самых префиксов.

```js
// Определение всех доступных префиксов
const stylePrefix = (() => {
  const prefix = ['webkit', 'moz', 'ms', 'o'].join('|')
  const replace = new RegExp(`^(${prefix})([A-Z])`)
  // Создадим карту соответствия имен
  const sp = new Map( /* "appRegion" => "webkitAppRegion", ... и т.д. */ )
  const all = Object.keys(window.getComputedStyle(document.createElement('div')))
    .filter((v) => !/[0-9]/.test(v))
  for (let s of all) {
    if (!replace.test(s)) {
      continue
    }
    // Некоторые стили повторяются и могут быть доступны как с префиксами, так и без
    // ... те что доступны не устанавливаем в sp:Map
    // webkitTransition => transition
    let pr = s.replace(replace, (_, __, ch) => ch.toLowerCase())
    if (!all.includes(pr))
      sp.set(pr, s)
  }
  // Кому интересно, можете скопировать участок кода "const stylePrefix = (...)()"
  // в консоль браузера и расскоментить эту строку
  // console.log(sp)
  return {
    has(s) {
      return sp.has(s)
    },
    get(s) {
      return sp.has(s) ? sp.get(s) : null
    }
  }
})()

// Пихаем это в нашу библиотеку
const myLib = {
  // Тут мы будем управлять стилями
  style: {
    set(element, styles) {
      for (let [s, v] of Object.entries(styles)) {
        element.style[stylePrefix.get(s) || s] = v
      } //, ...
    }
  },
  //...
}

// Далее используем в коде
const p = document.querySelector('p')
myLib.style.set(p,
  // Вот так удобнее использовать в любом участке кода,
  // и нет необходимости указывать префиксы
  {
    border: 'solid 10px #9e9e9e',
    borderStartColor: 'red' // НЕподдерживаемый стиль -webkit-border-start-color
  }
)

// Смотрим что реально установилось
console.log(`borderStartColor: ${p.style.borderStartColor}`)
console.log(`webkitBorderStartColor: ${p.style.webkitBorderStartColor}`)
```

```html
<p>Этому параграфу будет установлен -webkit-border-start-color</p>
```

Comment: В консоли разработчика в хроме не появляются свойства с префиксами

Comment: @Konstantin обновил

Answer (score 1):

```
this.menu.style.MozTransition = '...';
this.menu.style.WebkitTransition = '...';
this.menu.style.transition = '...';
```

Также обратите внимание на порядок свойств, свойство без префиксов нужно всегда давать в последнюю очередь. Иначе может быть так, что браузер поддерживает `transition` и `-webkit-transition`, но последним у Вас указан именно `-webkit-*`, то применится именно он. А это в свою очередь может повлечь ряд проблем с производительностью, как так префиксные свойства "под капотом" могут работать с багами.

Comment: В консоли разработчика в хроме не появляются свойства с префиксами

Comment: Не появляются, потому что браузер их игнорирует, т.к. поддерживается обычный transition